# Why is this sentence from The Great Gatsby grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, tenses, relative-pronouns

> There's a bird on the lawn that I think must be a nightingale come over on the Cunard or White Star Line.

According to my very limited knowledge, shouldn’t it be "which came over" in place of "come over"?

By this logic is it grammatical to say: "There’s a chicken come over on a plane"?

Comment: That would be a very unusual way to phrase it in American English today. Remember, *The Great Gatsby* is nearly a century old.

Comment: And it's still an understandable construct in some cases: "I think he's a tourist fresh off the plane." Although I think we'd usually put a comma before fresh.

Comment: I believe "come" is being used as a participle as in "Joy to the world, the Lord is come!"

Comment: Older English is like German.  There are two past perfect tense constructions.  While we use "has come" today, we used to say "is come".  Verbs of motion tended to take "is" rather than "has".

Comment: As a native US speaker, it doesn't sound unusual to me, but I'm over 60 and read a lot, so I might be biased on the subject of obsolescence.

Comment: I'm from the UK and this sentence doesn't sound unusual to me, it just sounds slightly colloquial.

Comment: As another native US speaker, this is comprehensible but definitely not normal phrasing. (I would have said "that came over".)  To me it sounds like slang I'm not familiar with, which would be appropriate for a slang phrase from a century ago.

Comment: +1 @DarthPseudonym, I also read this as a century-old ungrammatical colloquialism.

Comment: "They were come to the doors of Isengard."

Comment: That sentence copied from the Great Gatsby involves a relative clause having no relative pronoun, so there is no grammar gone wrong.

Comment: @daron "Were come" is different from "come" without a helper verb, but both of them are nonstandard constructions as far as my ear is concerned. Where "they were come to the doors" sounds intentionally archaic, "a nightingale come over on [a ship]" sounds colloquial or slangy. I'm not sure I can identify exactly why, but that's how it hits me.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym A more modern example "There is a man at the door, come to talk about Jesus." Well, that's a different "to" too.

Answer (score 26):

It's an example of a **[reduced relative clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_relative_clause)**

> A reduced relative clause is a relative clause that is not marked by an explicit relative pronoun or complementizer such as *who*, *which* or *that*. An example is the clause *I saw* in the English sentence *This is the man **I saw.*** Unreduced forms of this relative clause would be "This is the man *that* I saw." or "...*whom* I saw." *Wikipedia*

EDIT  15/03/23
(Many thanks to @Stef in the comments)  I hadn't considered the fact that F.Scott Fitzgerald would have used  **be** to form the perfect with the intransitive verb ‘come’ in “a nightingale **is** come over on the Cunard…”. Although *The Great Gatsby* was published in 1925, nearly a hundred years ago, I wasn't aware this construction, at least in American English, was still in use at the time and some native speakers would consider ‘come’ in ‘come over’ as an adjective.

*Dictionary.com* says [emphasis mine]

> 11. (used **in archaic** or **literary** constructions with some intransitive verbs to form the perfect tense):
>     *He is come*. *Agamemnon to the wars is gone.*

*[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/be)* offers this quote from Shakespeare's *Macbeth*, 1601

> 14. They **are** not yet come back.
>     <sub>instead of the modern *They **have** not yet come back.*</sub>

From the 1722 novel, *Moll Flanders*, by Daniel Defoe; we have two examples of the perfect tense used in the same excerpt.

> but at his Defire I altered that Resolution, and *[he is come over to England](https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_Fortunes_and_Misfortunes_of_the_Famo/Q7FgAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22is%20come%20over%22%20Moll%20Flanders&pg=PA324&printsec=frontcover)* alfo, where we refolve to spend the Remainder of our Years in fincere Penitence for the wicked Lives we **have lived**.

From *[The Tenant of Wildfell Hall](https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_tenant_of_Wildfell_Hall_by_Anne_Bron/a-0yAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22I%20don%27t%20know%20what%20is%20come%20over%20me%20of%20late%3B%22&pg=PA175&printsec=frontcover)* written by Anne Brontë in 1848

> I went down to dinner resolving to be cheerful and well-conducted, and kept my resolution very creditably, considering how my head ached, and how internally wretched I felt. I don't know **what is come over me** of late; my very energies, both mental and physical, must be strangely impaired,…

---

In *The Great Gatsby* quotation, the modernised version would be:

> …that I think must be a nightingale [which **has**] come over on the Cunard or White line

The relative clause with a present perfect construction could be replaced with ‘having’

> …that I think must be a nightingale **having** come over on the Cunard or White line.

Comment: It would be unexceptional to say "...brought over on the Cunard line" where brought is passive in meaning (the chicken is what was brought, it's not what was doing the bringing). I think what makes Fitzgerald's example unusual is that "come" is an intransitive verb, unlike "saw" or "brought".

Comment: @StuartF yes, that's a good explanation of what's happening here.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure it's an unusual expression for the 1920's.  "Come over on...[a ship or shipping line]" has the air of an idiomatic expression about it.

Comment: Normally you can't have a reduced relative clause if the antecedent is also the subject within the clause.

Comment: No, you can’t reduce like that. The reductions here are not correct: *a bird **that has come over** on a boat* → *a bird **come over** on a boat*. You can plainly see that here: *a boy **who has laughed** at a clown* → *a boy **laughed** at a clown*. And here: *the man **who has seen** me* → *the man **seen** me*. And here: *the child **who has eaten** candy* → *the child **eaten** candy*.

Comment: @StuartF "come over" reads like the bird got on the ship of its own volition — which it might well have.

Comment: Your answer is written in a way that suggests that the use of the past participle _come_ can introduce a legitimate "reduced relative clause" without the help of the auxiliary _have_ in the form of _which/that has_ or _having_. Given that the text was published in 1925, you'd need to provide some attested PDE examples where we can use the past participle _come_ without the auxiliary _have_. Otherwise, an edit is necessary to note that this construction _was_ a legitimate "reduced relative clause" a century ago, but not anymore.

Comment: I think the sentence would be a lot easier to read with a comma: "...a nightingale, come over on the...". I assume Fitzgerald left out the comma to give the impression of a stream of aimless dialogue tumbling out from the aimless empty-headed characters. That, or commas to separate clauses like this were not in fashion at the time.

Comment: Are we sure the auxiliary is "have" and not "is"? The past participle "come over" is almost used as an adjective here. *"A nightingale come over on the White Star Line"* sounds like the same grammatical construction as "A nightingale transported on the White Star Line". It helps that the Cunard and White Star Line are both shipping companies.

Comment: @Stef I hadn't considered that the auxiliary omitted was "is" but I think you are right. In the past, I know that the auxiliary  was used with past participles to form the present perfect that we find in many Bible passages and in 17-19th century works of literature: *He is risen*, *He is come* and one I found by Anne Brontë "I don't know **what is come over me** of late." Today, it would be "He has risen", "He has come" and "…has come over me"

Comment: @StuartF *Come over* is a transitive phrasal verb.

Answer (score 11):

The sentence uses **ellipsis** to convey meaning in an economical way. Although formal grammar might require "that has come over" or "that came over", the meaning is unambiguous and clear without such expansion of the text. The following general quotation from the Cambridge dictionary also serendipitously deals with your specific concern about the missing "which" or "that":

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/ellipsis)
> *Textual ellipsis*:
> When we can easily understand everything in the sentence because of the surrounding text, we use textual ellipsis. For example, we know that certain verbs and adjectives can be followed by a that-clause, so if we see a clause without that after such verbs and adjectives, we assume that the writer or speaker wants us to understand the same meaning as a that-clause:
> *I knew [that] something terrible had happened.*

If meaning is clear and unambiguous, insistence on formal grammar may merely seem pedantic and plodding. This raises the question of what should be the philosophical and operational basis of formal grammar; but that is too broad a topic to be tackled here.

Comment: English doesn't allow all "ellipsis" simply because the meaning remains unambiguous and clear. Whether a certain example of ellipsis is grammatical or not heavily depends on usage, which does change over time. The ellipsis of "that has" may have been possible and even natural back in 1925, but it doesn't seem to be anymore unless of course you can produce some recent examples of the past participle "come" being used without the help of the auxiliary _have_. Moreover, your "ellipsis" answer cannot explain how "that came" can transform into "come", because transformation is not ellipsis.

Comment: @JK2 *Moreover, your "ellipsis" answer cannot explain how "that came" can transform into "come",* **come** is simply an irregular colloquialism - very common.

Answer (score 1):

- This must be rain falling from the sky. (Said while the rain is falling.)
- This must be rain fallen from the sky. (Said after it has fallen.)

The word "come" in the quoted sentence is syntactically parallel to "fallen" in this example.

In English, past participles are usually *passive* participles, but in these examples they are being used as active participles. The present participle, "falling", is unambiguously active rather than passive.